# Smooth scrolling fixed div with css/javascript gives seemingly random results in IE

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a "left menu" and a "right menu" div that is absolutely positioned. I wanted them to follow the browser window while scrolling. My solution works really well in Opera, Firefox and Chrome, but the results in IE are unpredictable. Sometimes it works as intended, but sometimes the div's doesn't get the "position: absolute" style back.

Here is my code:

```
if(window.pageYOffset) {

    if(window.pageYOffset > 142) {

        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.top = "0";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.marginTop = "10px";

        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.top = "0";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.marginTop = "10px";

    } else {

        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.top = "152px";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.marginTop = "0px";

        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.top = "152px";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.marginTop = "0px";

    }

} else if(document.body && document.body.scrollTop) {

    if(document.body.scrollTop > 142) {

        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.top = "0";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.marginTop = "10px";

        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.top = "0";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.marginTop = "10px";

    } else {

        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.top = "152px";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.marginTop = "0px";

        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.top = "152px";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.marginTop = "0px";

    }

} else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {

    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 142) {

        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.top = "0";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.marginTop = "10px";

        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.top = "0";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.marginTop = "10px";

    } else {

        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.top = "152px";
        document.getElementById("menuRight").style.marginTop = "0px";

        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.top = "152px";
        document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.marginTop = "0px";

    }

}
```

What can I do to make the result in IE more predictable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that can be problem with your conditions. If scroll handler fires when scroll comes back to 0, then each condition will return `false` because `0` is converted to false. Easiest fix which comes to my mind is to add another else at the very end which will restore absolute position:

```
if(window.pageYOffset) {
    [...]
} else if(document.body && document.body.scrollTop) {
    [...]
} else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
    [...]
} else {

    document.getElementById("menuRight").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("menuRight").style.top = "152px";
    document.getElementById("menuRight").style.marginTop = "0px";

    document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.top = "152px";
    document.getElementById("menuLeft").style.marginTop = "0px";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pageYOffset` and `pageXOffset` are not supported in IE8 and before. You should start using jQuery, this code is kind of hard to look at. If you use jQuery, you cann make sure, that even IE will show the same results. Your code then would look like this

```
var pageXOffset = $(window).scrollLeft()
var pageYOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
var menuRight = $('#menuRight');
var menuLeft = $('#menuLeft');

if(pageYOffset) {
 if(pageYOffset > 142) {
  menuRight.css({position: "fixed", top: "0", marginTop: "10px"});
  menuLeft.css({position: "fixed", top: "0", marginTop: "10px"});
 } else {
  menuRight.css({position: "absolute", top: "152px", marginTop: "0px"});
  menuLeft.css({position: "absolute", top: "152px", marginTop: "0px"});
 }
} else if(document.body && document.body.scrollTop) {
 //etc.
}
```

Comment: You absolutely have a valid point here. I have been looking into jQuery and I sense that it's very dependable, but I just prefer to have perfect control. I want to know exactly what happens and I guess that comes with a price.

Comment: You will know what happens by using jQuery. It will solve 99% of issues that otherwise will need to be solved by noone else but yourself. If you don't use it you will learn that in order to keep things the same among all the browsers you need some kind of library that will perform different functions for different browsers to achieve the same goal. And if you still don't want to use jQuery you will end up writing one on your own.